# Using Android 4.0.3 to access a webservice using ksoap 2.6.0

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I am trying to get my Android phone to access the IDEOne (www.ideone.com) web service so I can use its APIs for this project I'm working on.  the webservice can be accessed using kSoap so I'm using kSoap 2.6.0 which I got from the Google website.  My code throws and exception on the following line of code:

httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request

I checked my wireless connection and used other wireless connection to make sure it was not a firewall problem.  I checked the connectionon the Android emulator and there was a connection.  I simply ran code others had posted online about connecting Android to web services via kSoap (http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data), with no luck.  It throws and exception on the same call function.  Any suggestions as to why?  Below is my code.  Thank you in advance for your help.

public class IDEOneStubI {

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "createSubmission";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ideone.com/api/1/service#createSubmission";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ideone.com/api/1/serviceL";
private static final String URL = "http://ideone.com/api/1/service;";
```

//you can get these values from the wsdl file^

```
public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
    request.addProperty("user", "nsbradley"); //variable name, value. I got the variable name, from the wsdl file!
    request.addProperty("pass", "12345678");
    request.addProperty("sourceCode", "Hello World");
    request.addProperty("language", 10);
    request.addProperty("input", "");
    request.addProperty("run", Boolean.TRUE);
    request.addProperty("private", Boolean.FALSE);
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope
   envelope.dotNet = true;
   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request
   HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);  
   httpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was
   httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
   SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response
   return result;
}
```

Comment: @user1183460 as chris said, you have to give us more details about exception and maybe the wsdl content. Meanwhile, make sure you have no mistakes in "namespace,...url". Are You sure your URL has a ";" inside quotations?ie -->"../1/services;";

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL string is wrong, remove the semicolon at the end and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 3.0, you must call this kind of methods from an async task.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you add permision to internet in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

if that doesnt work try changing

```
 SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response
```

to

```
 SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn; //get response
```

And also you should put the webservice calls in a try catch block, or throw a SoapFault exception.